# Starcraft 2 - Installation Help

Tags: starcraft-2

I have just bought Starcraft 2. I am in the process of installing it and it installs successfully, but then has to do some updates!

It has been updating for about 20 minutes and when it gets to 100% it starts again!

I have counted; 7 times has it has done the same update. what is going on?

Comment: happened to me at some point in the earlier updates. Had to cancel the update, thinking I screwed something up. On the next run it just started fine without having to update.

Answer (score 5):

Starcraft 2 has been out for several months now, and while the game itself has been updated (aka "Patched"), it is cost prohibitive to apply the same patches to the assembly-line copy that new DVDs of the game.

Just keep at it, and you *should* eventually reach the end.

Alternatively, register your game with battle.net, and you can download the latest version of the game directly from Blizzard themselves. This may not be an acceptable alternative if your internet connection is particularly slow.

Answer (score 0):

It may look like the game is applying an update over and over again, but it's actually applying each update since the original in sequence. Unlike most games, StarCraft II keeps old versions of itself lying around so that you can watch recordings and load saves from older versions of the game. There have been a bunch of updates since the game was first released, so the updater is applying all of them. Just give it time.